# How to swap 2 Span<char> without using stackalloc

Tags: c#, performance

Consider a writable string (Span, as a testcase only!)
like this:
"**hello world, how are you?**"

i have 2 spans from that.

**span1: "hello"**

**span2: "world"**

I cant find a good way to actually swap these 2 spans..
So that i have at the end:

"world hello, how are you?"

I would be very thankful if some1 could take up on this :-)

Best regards.

EDIT:
This is what I have already done but it uses sadly stackalloc i would love to allow swaping inmemory. :-)

```
 public static ReadOnlySpan<char> Swap(this ReadOnlySpan<char> main, ReadOnlySpan<char> a, ReadOnlySpan<char> b)
    {
        var needed = AsSpan(main.Slice(main.IndexOf(a), (a.Length + b.Length)));
        
        Span<char> aBuffer = stackalloc char[a.Length];
        AsSpan(a).CopyTo(aBuffer);
        Span<char> bBuffer = stackalloc char[b.Length];
        AsSpan(b).CopyTo(bBuffer);
        bBuffer.CopyTo(needed, out int writtenCount);
        aBuffer.CopyTo(needed[(writtenCount)..]);
        return needed;
    }
```

Comment: Can you write this as code, rather then a description of what you want to do?

Comment: span3 = span2, span2 = span1, span1 = span3.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable (read-only). If you are working with a string, you will always need a stackalloc to get a writeable copy of the string:

```
var str = "hello world, how are you?"
var span = stackalloc char[str.Length];
str.AsSpan().CopyTo(span);
```

Assuming you already have the message as a span, it *is* possible to swap data within the span without using another stackalloc. In this example, both the spans are 5 characters long. You can swap the individual characters one-by-one:

```
var part1 = span.Slice(0, 5);
var part2 = span.Slice(6, 5);

foreach (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var temp = part1[i];
    part1[i] = part2[i];
    part2[i] = temp;
}
```

Of course, this raises some questions:

- What should happen if the two spans being swapped are different lengths?
- Why do you care so much about not doing another stackalloc?
- Why not use the built-in string methods?

This looks like a case of premature optimization.

---

### Edit 1 - Implementation

The implementation you have posted only works if both spans are the same length. You've mentioned in the comments that this is not always the case. When handling different lengths, there are a few combinations of edge cases:

```
// The best case - both sections are the same length,
// so you don't have to shuffle any other memory around
// It doesn't matter if there is a gap
[_, _, _, a, a, a, b, b, b, _, _, _]
[_, _, _, a, a, a, x, x, x, b, b, b, _, _, _]

// The sections are not the same length, there is no gap
[_, _, _, a, a, b, b, b, b, _, _, _]
[_, _, _, a, a, a, a, b, b, _, _, _]

// The sections are not the same length, and there is a gap
[_, _, _, a, a, x, x, x, b, b, b, b, _, _, _]
[_, _, _, a, a, a, a, x, x, x, b, b, _, _, _]
```

The implementation needs to look at these cases, and handle each of them.

```
public static void Swap<T>(Span<T> span, int indexA, int lengthA, int indexB, int lengthB)
{
    var a = span.Slice(indexA, lengthA);
    var b = span.Slice(indexB, lengthB);

    if (lengthA == lengthB)
    {
        // The easy implementation
        var temp = stackalloc T[lengthA];
        a.CopyTo(temp);
        b.CopyTo(a);
        temp.CopyTo(b);
        return;
    }

    var destinationA = span.Slice(indexB + lengthB - lengthA, lengthA);
    var destinationB = span.Slice(indexA, lengthB);
    var indexX = indexA + lengthA;
    if (indexX == indexB)
    {
        // There is no gap between a and b
        var temp = stackalloc T[lengthA];
        a.CopyTo(temp);
        b.CopyTo(destinationB);
        temp.CopyTo(destinationA);
    }
    else
    {
        // There is a gap 'x' between 'a' and 'b' that needs to be moved too
        var lengthX = indexB - indexX;
        var x = span.Slice(indexX, lengthX);
        var destinationX = span.Slice(indexA + lengthB, lengthX);
        var tempA = stackalloc T[lengthA];
        var tempX = stackalloc T[lengthX];
        a.CopyTo(tempA);
        x.CopyTo(tempX);
        b.CopyTo(destinationB);
        tempX.CopyTo(destinationX);
        tempA.CopyTo(destinationA);
    }
}
```

Again, you mention wanting to do this without using 'stackalloc'. **Why?** Have you profiled your code, and found that there is a bottleneck in your swap method, specifically from the call to 'stackalloc'? I think you'll find that the performance of these few calls to 'stackalloc' is negligible, in comparison to the cost of using a for-loop instead of `Span.CopyTo()` (which can use `memcpy`)

Comment: hi, thx for the answer! I mean its important that there do not happen a new copy cause this thing comes from a stream and  I have to preserve its memory layout EXCEPT that i i am free to swap very specific spans, but i cannot just swap some of it, either swap the specific spans i get out from stream or dont swap at all!

Comment: I really wanna manipulate the original, consider this example here:

Comment: [UsefulSpan][IrrelavantSpan][UsefulSpan][IrrelavantSpan][UsefulSpan][IrrelavantSpan]

this shall look like this:

[IrrelavantSpan][IrrelavantSpan][IrrelavantSpan][UsefulSpan][UsefulSpan][UsefulSpan]

and irrelevant or useful span can be of different size!

Comment: So... you've loaded the whole thing in-memory? You can't just swap arbitrary sized chunks of memory around, you have to shuffle it all so there are no gaps. This is very do-able, please have a go at implementing it and show us what you have tried

Comment: Did you see my edit`?